# Extracting characters from text file

Tags: python, file, text, encryption

i have a text file that states:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I want to extract the characters in even positions starting at zero and create a string from them like string_even =`Teqikbonfxjmsoe h aydg`

as well as the characters in odd positions like string_odd = `h uc rw o up vrtelz o.`

i am just learning how to read text files and do not know how to approach this problem

Comment: How is this related to encryption?

Comment: the program i am writing is based on using the algorithm transposition cipher where i will decrypt and encrypt text files

Answer (score 3):

```
print txt[0::2]
print txt[1::2]
```